# Is it possible to reach the initial arrangement?

Tags: combinatorics

> We have a stack of $n$ books piled on each other, and labeled by $1, 2, ..., n$. In each round we make $n$ moves in the following manner: In the $i$-th move of each turn, we turn over the $i$ books at the top, as a single book. After each round we start a new round similar to the previous one. Show that after some moves, we will reach the initial arrangement.

---

Say $n=4$ and initial arrangement of books $(a,b,c,d)$. First we act on it with identical transformation $\pi_1=id$ which leaves everything as it was. Then we act on it with 
$$\pi_2 = \left(
\begin{array}\\
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
    2 & 1 & 3 & 4 
\end{array}\right)$$
and we get $(b,a,c,d)$, then we act on this one with $$\pi_3 = \left(
\begin{array}\\
    1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
    3 & 2 & 1 & 4 
\end{array}\right)$$ and we get $(c,a,b,d)$ and then $$\pi_4 = \left(
\begin{array}\\
   1 & 2 & 3 & 4  \\
    4 & 3 & 2 & 1 
\end{array}\right)$$ and we get $(d,b,a,c)$ and then we repeat acting with $$\pi_1,\pi_2,\pi_3,\pi_4,\pi_1,\pi_2,...$$

Now what do we get if we repeat enough time $$\sigma = \pi_4\circ \pi_3\circ \pi_2\circ \pi_1$$ on starting $(a,b,c,d)$? If we repeat this $\sigma $ exactly $24$ times (which is the order of symmetric group $S_4$) we shoud get initialy arrangment. Clearly this can be easly generalized for arbitrary $n$.

Is this correct?

---

**Edit:** As suggested in comment by Lord Shark the Unknown, It shoud be considered also the first and last front of a book. So I should observe  8-couple $(a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2,d1,d2)$, where $x1$ is first front and $x2$ last one, instead of 4-couple $(a,b,c,d)$ and act on it with $S_8$?

Comment: Don't forget, you are turning the books over, and need to account for whether they are upside down or the right way up.

Comment: So, I should study 8-couple $(a1,a2,b1,b2,c1,c2,d1,d2)$ instead of 4-couple $(a,b,c,d)$ and act on it with $S_8$? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: To clarify, all we do is turn the books over? Or turn them over and move them to the bottom?

Comment: As I understand it is first one @pwerth

Comment: @greedoid Then I am a bit confused. Consider $n=2$. At the first move, we flip the top book. At the second move, and every move thereafter, we flip both books. So they will never end up facing the same way..

Comment: Well, I get the same configuration after 8-th move. @pwerth

Comment: Fun fact: This [problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting) is the subject of Bill Gates' sole [mathematics paper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pancake_sorting#cite_note-Gates1979-3).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $S$ be the set of $2n$ book covers. Each round is a permutation of $S$. Every permutation $\pi$ of a finite set has a number $k$ such that $\pi^k=\text{id}$. One can choose $k$ to be the lcm of the cycle lengths of $\pi$.

For example, when $n=2$, a single round looks like this, where capital letters are the top cover and lower case are the bottom cover.

```
A    a    b
a    A    B
B    B    A
b    b    a
```

In cycle notation, this looks like $(A\;\; B\;\; a\;\; b)$. This a cycle of order four, so four rounds suffice to return the books to their original order.

Answer (score 1):

For clear reference, here is a complete cycle of moves. Negative number represents book face down.

```
 1  2  3  4 
-1  2  3  4 
-2  1  3  4 
-3 -1  2  4 
-4 -2  1  3 
 4 -2  1  3 
 2 -4  1  3 
-1  4 -2  3 
-3  2 -4  1 
 3  2 -4  1 
-2 -3 -4  1 
 4  3  2  1 
-1 -2 -3 -4 
 1 -2 -3 -4 
 2 -1 -3 -4 
 3  1 -2 -4 
 4  2 -1 -3 
-4  2 -1 -3 
-2  4 -1 -3 
 1 -4  2 -3 
 3 -2  4 -1 
-3 -2  4 -1 
 2  3  4 -1 
-4 -3 -2 -1 
 1  2  3  4 << return to initial state
```